# Card emulation app related technologies

Tags: applet, smartcard

Hi I am trying to develop an app that can talk to applets installed in UICC and enable payments.

When working on it , I lost a little bit because of lack of domain knowledge and it would be great help on following questions,

1. Global Platform vs Open Card Framework and Java Card, what is the different?
2. I found that I have to deal with CRS and so many different applets related to GP but I am lost here to understand what is the stack of these technologies?

Answer (score 2):

Javacard specifies the runtime that runs your app (VM specs, bytecode format, general purpose APIs). What javacard does not cover is how applications are deployed, and managed remotely. This is the main purpose of GlobalPlatform card specification. GP defines a concept of security domains which support external stakeholder's assets in the card (application, data and security keysets). GlobalPlatform makes it possible to a third party to discuss with the card's issuer and deploy its secrets and assets in a way that the issuer cannot know about these. "OpenPlatform" is the former name of GlobalPlatform I believe.